# Nonpositive curvature with closing geodesics.

Tags: calculus, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields, curvature, geodesic

Let $M$ be a complete Riemannian manifold, $x \in M$ a point, and
$\gamma_s(t)$ be a family of geodesics starting at $x$ at time $t=0$,
$s \in [-\epsilon,\epsilon]$. The Jacobi field $J(s,t)$ of this family satisfies
$J(s,0) = 0$. Moreover, the Taylor expansion of the length in $t$
looks like

$$ J(0,t) = 0 + t^2 |J'(t)|^2 + t^4 R + O(t^6) $$

where $R$ denotes the sectional curvature of the plan spanned by
the family at the initial point. Intuitively, this suggests in
particular that negative curvature implies that the geodesics'
spreading out. **However, this is just a local result. Plus, $J$
isn't analytic in general**, so the Taylor estimate might not hold
on the nose even in any small neighborhood.

Thus my question: is there a compact Riemannian manifold with
non-positive curvature everywhere such that a pair of geodesics starting from the same point with different initial direction meets up somewhere else?

---

**EDIT** Yes there are, given in the comment below: a surface of genus $g \geq 2$ has many closed geodesics, which serve as examples I want.

A new question: what about those for $M$ which is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: What do you mean by close up? If you mean a closed geodesic, then the cylinder is an example. Or even the circle

Comment: And for negative curvature, for hyperbolic surfaces (with genus $g \geqslant 2$), there are many closed geodesics (one in each non-trivial free-homotopy class).

Comment: @ArcticChar thanks for the comment. I have edited my last paragraph to make it more formal and clearer. Dldier_ my apologies too. Please see the edited version. The estimate that i used is really meant for geodesics starting from the same point.

Comment: Concerning your revised question, any closed geodesics still gives you counterexample: pick any point $p=\gamma)(t_0)$ in the closed geodesic. Then the two geodesics with initial velocity $\pm \gamma' (t_0)$ will meet at some other point.

Comment: Ah.. yeah indeed. I might have to revise it again. The closed geodesics on the higher genus surfaces still split out at first (in a local view).. but since the surface is compact, they can come back to each other from another side. A better formulation might in fact require the manifold to be open, or even just $\mathbb{R}^n$.. but I will have to think more before I revise.